# Retrieve specific number of records from database - JPA (Impove performance)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, persistence

I found several solutions on internet, but in performance aspect those are not what i searched for. I have a table with records more than 10,000,000 records. I need to **read only last 150 results**.

```
query.select(trailRoot).distinct(Boolean.TRUE)
    .where(buildPredicateForAuditTrail(auditTrailCriteria, criteriaBuilder, trailRoot));

final TypedQuery<AuditTrail> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(query);
return typedQuery.setFirstResult(auditTrailCriteria.calculateFirstResultIndex())
    .setMaxResults(150).getResultList();
```

**This code does the job.** But it still reads all 10,000,000 records from db **which makes a huge overload in web server**. Can I simply limit the query like,

```
SELECT *FROM Persons LIMIT 5;
```

Is there a way to limit the result by query itself ??
Any help is highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You can try something like `SELECT TOP 150 * FROM Persons ORDER BY ID DESC`

Comment: @saviNuclear you mean a named query??

Comment: LIMIT is clearly not a JPQL keyword, neither is "*" valid ... see any JPQL reference. MaxResults/FirstResult are what you set for JPQL

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you set first result to a specific offset?

```
query.setFirstResult(firstResult);
query.setMaxResults(maxResults);
```

Have a look at LazyCarDataModel.java http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/lazy.xhtml

Comment: Thank you for the reply. of course i can do it. Setting max results does the job. But my issue is query still reads all the 10,000,000  records from the db and then limit the resultset. That is the peocess i want to get rid of. I want to limit the result by query itself.

Comment: 1. If you want to limit the results by the query itself you'll have to add some conditions in your where clause I'm afraid...
2. In the case I described (in which you select a portion) JPA would send a query that includes OFFSET and LIMIT to the underlying DBMS. So when the select is slow JPA/Hibernate are not to blame ;)

Comment: JPA uses setFirstResult and setMaxResults directly when building the SQL query, usually LIMIT keyword is used with the value passed to MaxResults, but that depends on the database type and the JPA provider settings. Are you sure that the JPA query retrieves all the records and not only maxResults records? If yes, pelase write what is your database (MySQL?)? Hibernate should be configured with the correct dialect for your database in order to build the query correctly.